# Handling multiple carts in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm wondering if there is a shorter solution for my problem.

I'm currently building a multiple shop system, which means a website with different shops where you have 1 open cart for each shop.

This cart can be owned from a guest or a user.

The cart/order should only be created when an item is added.

The following definition is placed in the application controller.

```
 def find_order_by_shop(shop)
   shop = Shop.find(shop.to_i) if !(shop.class == Shop)
   if session["order_id_for_shop_#{shop.try(:id)}"]
     order = Order.find_by_id_and_state(session["order_id_for_shop_#{shop.id}"],'open')
     if order
       if current_user
         current_user.orders.where(:shop_id => shop.id , :state => 'open').where.not(:id => session["order_id_for_shop_#{shop.id}"]).delete_all
         order.update_attribute(:user_id, current_user.id)
         order = current_user.orders.where(:shop_id => shop.id , :state => 'open').first
         if order
           # delete all exept first
           current_user.orders.where(:shop_id => shop.id , :state => 'open').where.not(:id => order.id).delete_all
         else
           # create new
           order = current_user.orders.new(:shop_id => shop.id , :state => 'open')
         end
       end
     else
       order = Order.new(:shop_id => shop.id, :state => 'open')
     end
   else
     if current_user
        order = current_user.orders.where(:shop_id => shop.id , :state => 'open').first
        if order
          current_user.orders.where(:shop_id => shop.id , :state => 'open').where.not(:id => order.id).delete_all
        else
          order = current_user.orders.new(:shop_id => shop.id , :state => 'open')
        end
      else
        # guest
        order = Order.new(:shop_id => shop.id , :state => 'open')
      end
   end

   session["order_id_for_shop_#{shop.try(:id)}"] = order.id
   return order
 end
```

Updating the session while adding an item to the cart/order

```
 ...
   def create # add item to order
     @order = find_order_by_shop(params[:shop_id].to_i)
     @order.save # save cart
     session["order_id_for_shop_#{params[:shop_id]}"] = @order.id
 ...
```

This doesn't seem to be the correct rails way.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Don't you think a user should always have a single cart regardless of what he's buying? And your code is not readable there are just too many if else statements

Comment: The user should can checkout several orders at once, and while switching between the shop he should see the current cart of this shop, because he also can checkout just one order from one shop. Yes i know there are to many if/else that's because i don't know how to solve it cleaner...

Comment: Still don't get the point of having multiple carts. You have one site for different shops, don't you? As a user i'll be much more happier if i have a single cart rather than having multiple carts and then trying to figure out which cart has which items :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about 'shorter', but just glancing at your code I would make a few recommendations.

Each change you make, test the code. Hopefully you have unit and functional tests, if not then check expected behaviour in a browser.

Try to split your logic into sensible, small, tight units with sensible names. Turn them into methods. As you do so, you may find some problems or points where you could optimise. For example:

```
if order
  if current_user
    current_user.orders.where(:shop_id => shop.id , :state => 'open').where.not(:id => session["order_id_for_shop_#{shop.id}"]).delete_all
    order.update_attribute(:user_id, current_user.id)
    order = current_user.orders.where(:shop_id => shop.id , :state => 'open').first
    if order
      # delete all exept first
      current_user.orders.where(:shop_id => shop.id , :state => 'open').where.not(:id => order.id).delete_all
    else
      # create new
      order = current_user.orders.new(:shop_id => shop.id , :state => 'open')
    end
  end
else
  order = Order.new(:shop_id => shop.id, :state => 'open')
end
```

As there's an 'if order' conditional around this whole block, the internal 'if order' is redundant and the whole 'else' branch can be removed:

```
if order
  if current_user
    current_user.orders.where(:shop_id => shop.id , :state => 'open').where.not(:id => session["order_id_for_shop_#{shop.id}"]).delete_all
    order.update_attribute(:user_id, current_user.id)
    order = current_user.orders.where(:shop_id => shop.id , :state => 'open').first
    # delete all except first
    current_user.orders.where(:shop_id => shop.id , :state => 'open').where.not(:id => order.id).delete_all
  end
else
  order = Order.new(:shop_id => shop.id, :state => 'open')
end
```

Now you can split the functionality up into small, reusable blocks:

```
def order_from_shop(shop_id)
  Order.new(:shop_id => shop_id, :state => 'open')
end
```

Look through your code and you can see at least two places that you can use this method.

Notice that there is no return statement. The Ruby/Rails 'way' is to allow the automatic return to kick in - the result of the last statement in a method is returned without explicitly declaring it. You can apply this to the end of your main method:

```
  ...
  session["order_id_for_shop_#{shop.try(:id)}"] = order.id
  order
end
```

Back to the rest of the code, start extracting more methods, like:

```
def user_order_from_shop(shop_id)
  current_user.orders.where(:shop_id => shop.id , :state => 'open').first
end
```

There's a few places you can use that, too.

Encapsulate your `if` statements in small methods, of the form:

```
def method
  if xxx
    a_method
  else
    a_different_method
  end
end
```

According to Sandi Metz, no method should have more than 5 lines. You don't have to be that extreme but it's useful to do so.

Eventually you'll have something that reads a lot more like English, so will be much easier to read and to determine the behaviour of at a glace. At that point you may well notice a lot more duplication or unnecessary, dead chunks of unreachable code. Be ruthless with both.

Finally, this whole thing looks like it needs its own class.

```
# app/services/shop_order_query.rb
class ShopOrderQuery
  attr_accessor :shop, :order, :current_user

  def initialize(shop, order, current_user)
    self.shop = shop
    self.order = order
    self.current_user = current_user
  end

  def find_order_by_shop
    ...
    ...
  end

  private

  # support methods for main look-up

  def order_from_shop(shop_id)
    ...
  end
  ...
  ...
end
```

Then call it with

```
ShopOrderQuery.new(shop, order, current_user).find_order_by_shop
```

Then it's all nicely tucked away, and usable from wherever you can pass it a shop, order and current user... And it's not cluttering up your controller.

For further reading, look for blog posts on making thin controllers, extracting service objects and Sandi Metz's Rules. Also, buy Sandi's book on Ruby OO programming.

Comment: Once you've refactored your code you'll have a nice, isolated class that operates just on the entities you pass in to it. This makes testing a lot easier, as you can use mock objects in order to test the behaviour of the class without having to drag around the controller object or do any database look-ups. Neat, huh? Then you just need to test the behaviour of the public method(s).